# What is the use of Kubernetes deployment port configuration since we have that option while configuring service?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

There is already a port we are exposing at docker using `EXPOSE` in Dockerfile and again at Kubernetes service.yaml using `port` and `targetPort`; Those are understandable. But why there is a need to specify a port at Kubernetes deployment.yaml? Am I missing some concepts here?

Answer (score 5):

Following the Kubernetes documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/):

> List of ports to expose from the container. Exposing a port here gives
>   the system additional information about the network connections a
>   container uses, but is primarily informational. Not specifying a port
>   here DOES NOT prevent that port from being exposed. Any port which is
>   listening on the default "0.0.0.0" address inside a container will be
>   accessible from the network.

So `ports` in `Deployment` is used for informational purpose. It is similar to `EXPOSE` in the Dockerfile. The main reason is helping people who maintain the deployment understand the configuration better.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're asking about the `ports.containerPort`. That specifies the port exposed by the pod. It is mostly informational because any port the pod is listening on can be connected. However, you can give a name to the port this way.

The `EXPOSE` in Dockerfile is mostly informational. The `port` and `targetPort` in a service are required. Port is the port number (and name) the service is listening on, and targetPort is the port on a pod the service is forwarding to.

Answer (score 0):

It has been talked about [many times](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/425) over the years but basically a decision early on was to ignore the EXPOSE metadata from the container as Docker Networking and CNI have subtly different models. Specifically CNI avoids a layer of NAT when exposing container ports because it wanted to emulate a globally flat network.